# Outlook 2016 with multiple account setup using the wrong "From" email when replying or forwarding messages

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-office-2016

I have set up my Outlook 2016 with my Outlook email account using the "**Auto Account Setup**". Outlook added this as a Microsoft Exchange account. I also setup a few of my other IMAP accounts.

It appears that with the setup above, when I reply to or forward an email from one of my IMAP accounts, the "**From**" email has been populated with my Outlook (Exchange) account. I can however manually change this. If I don't change this and send the email, the recipient sees "**Email from IMAP account on behalf of Outlook account**"

I do not want this behaviour. How can I change this so the email in the "**From**" field is auto selected with the email address of the email account being used, for example, my IMAP account? Is this by design or a bug?

When creating new emails, this does not happen.

I have found a workaround which did not work for me:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-client-multiple-accounts-reply-and/dd7927d3-238b-4241-8e73-76fb2c0808b0?auth=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround which will have to do until Microsoft fix this bug.

You have to change the default data file to be a .PST one, maybe your "Local Folders". After which the replies and forwarded messages will select the correct "From" email address.

Problem with this is that now I have "Local Folders" in my folder (navigation) pane, which I have no use for.

Note that the Calendar and/or the To-Do Bar may not work as expected after doing this. I'm not bothered about that as I don't use the Outlook calendar.

More info:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/solved-outlook-2016-uses-wrong-account-on-forward/e675b704-63a5-4bbd-a434-d3c3695cbe34